# What Excel function is appropriate for the following scenario?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an issue I'm running into using Excel (I need to utilize Excel for this project). I need to create a table that generates the percentage of trips that begin during each hour during the day (assuming 24 hours in a day, of course). I've already established the times during which each trip started and the total number of trips that occurred, but I'm having trouble writing a equation that would accept the total number of trips and divide that by a time range (i.e. 3:00:00 AM to 3:59:00 AM) and output the percentage of trips that occurred. I've tried using =SUMIF and =SUMIFS, since they seem the most appropriate. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: please [edit] the post to include a [mcve].  That would include mock data and expected output based on the mock data.  It would also include the formula you tried that got you the closest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. It sounds like you want the percentage of total trips that fall within that hour range. If so, you need to use a combination of `COUNTIF`, `COUNT` (or `COUNTA`, which I prefer), and `HOUR`. I couldn't get `HOUR` to work within `COUNTIF` to calculate the hour range or the condition, so I don't see a way to avoid adding a hidden column (which I hate to do).

`HOUR()` returns the hour in military time/24 hour time. If no time is given (e.g. date only), it returns 0.

Assume your table has headers and data is only from rows 2 to 20 where `Column A = Trip Start Time`, Column B is (hidden) Hour, and `Column C = % Trips`

```
Cell B2: =HOUR($A2) 
Cell C2: =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$20,"=$B2")/COUNTA($B$2:$B$20)
```

And so on, copied down all of the rows. Note I use dollar signs on the column (and row for range) so that I can easily copy down functions without having them screw up

Comment: Thanks, Tyler2P!

Answer (score 1):

If your table isn't what Excel considers to be an actual table then highlight your entire source table and click "Insert - Table".

Besides formatting, one of the huge benefits to this is that, when possible, you can store a one formula per COLUMN instead of one formula per cell. If column title of the start times is "Start Time" then you can create a new column, enter a formula of `=HOUR([@[Start Time]])` in one of the cells, and suddenly the whole column is populated.

From there, you can make a Pivot Table to get what you need, right?